# How do i colorize output files

Tags: r, centos

I would to know how to colorize the output file. I use the package *crayon* for coloring print and message. I understand that it is slurm who manages the files *out* and *err* so it is normal that the files are not colorized but would there be a way through Rscript?

**test.R**

```
message(crayon::cyan("message"))
print(crayon::yellow("print"))
sr <- crayon::make_style("red")
cat(crayon::style("cat \n", sr))
```

**in console**

```
$ Rscript test.R >& output.R
```

Comment: The color comes from the file viewer... This is basically syntax highlighting... I don't thing you would write files like this with R, except you write some kind of hypertext or rich text or so...

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. There is no way to make a color output file?

Comment: @problème0123 do you mean colors like in `ls -alh` or `grep something file`? Look e.g. here: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting or search for "bash ansi colors"

Comment: Hello, I just want to put a color to the characters, it is possible to generate an output file in pdf format to have the colors? (I corrected my post).